# Recursive multi-level category

Tags: java, arrays, json, recursion

I have a multi-level category like this.

By some way i got data like this, not include root category.

How can i build a mutil-level category Json data as:

```
--PHP
---Codeigniter
----Tutorials
-----Basic
-----Advance
----Course
---Laravel
--JAVASCRIPT
----AngularJS
----Jquery
--JAVA
---Basic
```

Here my code example:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XMXcxIsboydP1bSoBeZZFOrKDDo8SxnQW2H1Wh69O-Q

Comment: i know must using recursion. But my code not work. Please read and help me. i dont know apply recursion in my case.

Answer (score 0):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XMXcxIsboydP1bSoBeZZFOrKDDo8SxnQW2H1Wh69O-Q

With this code, result is

```
Basic
--PHP
---Codeigniter
----Tutorials
-----Basic
-----Advance
----Course
---Laravel
--JAVASCRIPT
----AngularJS
----Jquery
--JAVA
---Basic
```

Near success.